# Add Toggle Menu to Nav Bar

Tags: css, html

How do I modify the code so that when the screen is reduced to 768px, the nav bar becomes a toggle menu?. For smaller screens I would like the nav bar to display the hamburger toggle symbol and for each menu and sub-menu item to become clickable instead of hover. Thank you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main-nav a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #d3333b;
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

#main-nav a:hover {
  background: #777;
}

#main-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

#main-nav li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#main-nav li:hover .submenu>li {
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
}

.submenu li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.submenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-right: auto;
  /* 1 */
  margin-left: auto;
  /* 1 */
  max-width: 960px;
  /* 2 */
  padding-right: 10px;
  /* 3 */
  padding-left: 10px;
  /* 3 */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Flexbox Dropdown Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 1.1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 1.2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 1.3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 1.4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 1.5</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 1.6</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 1.7</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 2.1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 2.2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 2.3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Will you use bootstrap?

Comment: I am not sure what bootstrap is. I would like the website to be accessible on the main browsers and handheld devices.

Comment: I recommend you to use `bootstrap`, if no, then you can add `media-queries` and make div `block` or `none` on mobile or desktop, you can also use `JavaScript`

Comment: I would like to use a media-query. How do I modify the code?

Comment: have a look into the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">CSS Nav</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Our Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for all of the code to be modified. I don't know what code to put inside the media query I am a beginner.

Comment: That looks nice, but when I add text in the <body> to your code the text sits behind the header. How do I stop the header from overlaying the body? And how do I add a submenu (hover in full screen, clickable in 768 px screen)?

Comment: Yeah text will hide behind the `header` because it is fixed. So u need to move down by giving `margin-top` to it.